# How to identify/use selected radio button by another button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a button, that will work according to the options selected by radio buttons.  According to the code bellow if 'Option1' radio button is selected, ' 1st option selected' should be printed out when test button is clicked.  For 'Option 2' radio button ' 2nd option selected' should be printed out when test button is clicked.  But I got always '1st option selected'.  If anyone can help.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Select:
    def __init__ (self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title ('Title')
        root.geometry ('100x100')

        button1 = Radiobutton (self.root, text = 'Option 1', command = self.option1, value = 1).place (x = 10, y = 10)
        button2 = Radiobutton (self.root, text = 'Option 2', command = self.option2, value = 2).place (x = 10, y = 30)

        test = Button (self.root, text = 'Run', command = self.test).place (x = 10, y = 70)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def option1 (self):
        print ' Option 1'        

    def option2 (self):
        print ' Option 2'


    def test (self):        
        if self.option1:
            print ' 1st option selected'
        elif self.option2:
            print '2nd option selected'
        else:
            print 'No option selected'

Select(Tk()).test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if self.option1:` is always true, since what you're asking is just whether self.option1 -- a method pointer -- is non-zero. You're not even calling the function (that would require parentheses after the name), but if you were, it would return the result of the `print` statement, which isn't what you want either. What needs to happen in option1() (as well as in option2()) is that you set a flag, accessible from outside the function, to indicate that it was run.

For example:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Select:
    def __init__ (self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title ('Title')
        root.geometry ('100x100')

        button1 = Radiobutton (self.root, text = 'Option 1', command = self.option1, value = 1).place (x = 10, y = 10)
        button2 = Radiobutton (self.root, text = 'Option 2', command = self.option2, value = 2).place (x = 10, y = 30)

        test = Button (self.root, text = 'Run', command = self.test).place (x = 10, y = 70)
        self.flag = 0
        self.root.mainloop()

    def option1 (self):
        print ' Option 1'        
        self.flag = 1

    def option2 (self):
        print ' Option 2'
        self.flag = 2

    def test (self):        
        if self.flag == 1:
            print '1st option selected'
        elif self.flag == 2:
            print '2nd option selected'
        else:
            print 'No option selected'

Select(Tk()).test()
```